# C RS232 comm. How to compare CPU time?

Tags: c, time, serial-port, cpu

First time posting so there's probably gonna be more info than necessary but I wanna be thorough:

One of our exercises in C was to create sender and receiver programs that would exchange data via RS232 serial communication with null modem. We used a virtual port program (I used the trial version of Virtual Serial Port by eltima software if you want to test). We were required to do 4 versions:

1) Using a predetermined library created by a previous student that had sender and reveiver etc. premade functions
2) Using the inportb and outportb functions
3) Using OS interrupt int86 and giving register values through the REGS union
4) Using inline assembly

Compiler: DevCPP (Bloodshed).

All worked, but now we are required to compare all the different versions based on the CPU time that is spent to send and receive a character. It specifically says that we have to find the following:

average, standard deviation, min, max and 99,5 %

Nothing was explained in class so I'm a little lost here...I'm guessing those are statistical numbers after many trials of the normal distribution? But even then how do I actually measure CPU cycles on this? I'll keep searching but I'm posting here in the mean time 'cause the deadline is in 3 days :D.

Code sample of the int86 version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dos.h>

#define RS232_INIT_FUNCTION 0
#define RS232_SEND_FUNCTION 1
#define RS232_GET_FUNCTION 2
#define RS232_STATUS_FUNCTION 3
#define DATA_READY 0x01

#define PARAM 0xEF
#define COM1 0
#define COM2 1


void rs232init (int port, unsigned init_code)
{
     union REGS inregs;
     inregs.x.dx=port;
     inregs.h.ah=RS232_INIT_FUNCTION;
     inregs.h.al=init_code;
     int86(0x14,&inregs,&inregs);
}

unsigned char rs232transmit (int port, char ch)
{
     union REGS inregs;
     inregs.x.dx=port;
     inregs.h.ah=RS232_SEND_FUNCTION;
     inregs.h.al=ch;
     int86(0x14,&inregs,&inregs);
     return (inregs.h.ah);
}

unsigned char rs232status(int port){
     union REGS inregs;
     inregs.x.dx=port;
     inregs.h.ah=RS232_STATUS_FUNCTION;
     int86(0x14, &inregs, &inregs);
     return (inregs.h.ah);  //Because we want the second byte of ax
     }

unsigned char rs232receive(int port)
{
    int x,a;
    union REGS inregs;
    while(!(rs232status(port) & DATA_READY))
    {
        if(kbhit()){
            getch();
            exit(1); 
            }
        };
    inregs.x.dx=port;
    inregs.h.ah=RS232_GET_FUNCTION;
    int86(0x14,&inregs,&inregs);
    if(inregs.h.ah & 0x80)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        return -1;
    }
    return (inregs.h.al);
}

int main(){
    unsigned char ch;
    int d,e,i;

    do{
        puts("What would you like to do?");
        puts("1.Send data");
        puts("2.Receive data");
        puts("0.Exit");
        scanf("%d",&i);
        getchar();

        if(i==1){
           rs232init(COM1, PARAM);

           puts("Which char would you like to send?");
           scanf("%c",&ch);
           getchar();
           while(!rs232status(COM1));
           d=rs232transmit(COM1,ch);
           if(d & 0x80) puts("ERROR");   //Checks the bit 7 of ah for error
        }
        else if(i==2){
           rs232init(COM1,PARAM);
           puts("Receiving character...");
           ch=rs232receive(COM1);
           printf("%c\n",ch);
        }
    }while(i != 0);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What hardware/OS are you running on? That won't help much with your question, but I'm curious.  The question is a little devious. 'CPU time that is spent to send and receive a character' - timed from what to where?  You could say that the 'in' and 'out' instructions, to and from the UART in the I/O map, are all that is needed.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 and as I said i'm running an emulator. It creates port pairs and we work on those, but it emulates a 16550 or 8250 UART. I'm guessing that when using in and out instructions it depends on the instruction as to how fast it will resolve? For example inline assembly should be the fastest since you directly give values to the registers and they're ready to send whereas using a premade library has to go through functions and then find the registers etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is some guesswork required here because the question is a little undefined.

You've listed four different methods for sending/receiving a character. What I suspect your lecturer is looking for is the time from when you call the method given (or enter your inline assembly code) to the time when you return from the method (leave inline code). You will need to grab a time just before the call and just after the call and find their difference.

Less ambiguous is cpu time. The clock() method is the most straightforward way to do this, however this may not be what the lecturer is looking for.

Finally are the statistics, which is straightforward. Do a bunch of runs, and run some statistics on the times

Comment: I will check the clock() method. In the meantime I asked on our forums about a clarification on the matter, I'll be posting again if I get an answer

Comment: The clarification that was given was to count the time the program needs from entering the function to exiting it. I'm guessing this means I will put 2 functions that show time before and after? Can this be done with the clock() method?

Comment: Correct, one function before, one function after. As to which functions, if you want cpu time, then clock() will work. However you could also use gettimeofday() and that will simply get the current time. Could do both for the heck of it.